# Oracle Apex 5 - Interactive report - Header not visible

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I'm having some problem with some Interactive Reports: the header of them it's not visible (but I can see the "space" reserved to it) until I don't perform a research: after it they become visible. 
Some details more:

- Application Express 5.0.4.00.12
- The first column of the report is hidden
- If the first column is set as Link with a small image the header works normally.
- I'm using the default thema.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: More infos: I realized the problem is the default template for the collapsable item: when the item as default is "collapsed" the problem appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: in the attribute the Header setting "Fixed To" as to be fixed in "None", and it was in "Page".